# SELECT WHERE IN - mySQL

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

let's say I have the following Table:

```
 ID, Name 
 1, John 
 2, Jim 
 3, Steve 
 4, Tom
```

I run the following query

```
SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE NAME IN ('John', 'Jim', 'Bill');
```

I want to get something like:

```
ID
1
2
NULL or 0
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by creating a subquery of names you're looking for, then left join the subquery to your table:

```
SELECT myTable.ID
FROM (
  SELECT 'John' AS Name
  UNION SELECT 'Jim'
  UNION SELECT 'Bill'
) NameList
LEFT JOIN myTable ON NameList.Name = myTable.Name
```

This will return `null` for each name that isn't found. To return a zero instead, just start the query with `SELECT COALESCE(myTable.ID, 0)` instead of `SELECT myTable.ID`.

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/599d0/1).

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE NAME IN ('John', 'Jim', 'Bill')
   UNION
SELECT null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit confusing. "IN" is a valid operator in SQL and it means a match with any of the values (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) ):

```
SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE NAME IN ('John', 'Jim', 'Bill');
```

Is the same as:

```
SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE NAME = 'John' OR NAME = 'Jim' OR NAME = 'Bill';
```

In your answer you seem to want the replies for each of the values, in order. This is accomplished by joining the results with UNION ALL (only UNION eliminates duplicates and can change the order):

```
SELECT max(Id) FROM Table WHERE NAME = 'John' UNION ALL
SELECT max(Id) FROM Table WHERE NAME = 'Jim' UNION ALL
SELECT max(Id) FROM Table WHERE NAME = 'Bill';
```

The above will return 1 Id (the max) if there are matches and NULL if there are none (e.g. for Bill). Note that in general you can have more than one row matching some of the names in your list, I used "max" to select one, you may be better of in keeping the loop on the values outside the query or in using the (ID, Name) table in a join with other tables in your database, instead of making the list of ID and then using it.